# image import Magento 1.8

Tags: import, image, magmi, dataflow, ce-1.8.0.0

I am having problems importing my images in Magento CE 1.8, I have followed all the procedures

CSV have the following columns
sku _attribute_set  _type   _category   _root_category  _product_websites   att_cost    att_eby_title   att_upc created_at  description external_image  external_small_image    external_thumbnail  image   manufacturer    msrp    name    price   short_description   small_image status  tax_class_id    thumbnail   visibility  weight  qty _media_image

the data is formatted in field="," text=" "

The image fields are in this format "/TUSHT134SLR252f140fc3bf32.jpg"

The Images are in the /media/import/ Directory

I have tried pulling the leading "/" on my image fields, that didnt work (as expected)

I keep getting "image not found" error on the import

I have used Import, Dataflow and Magmi all three give me the same error!

Comment: save csv at .utf8 format

Comment: Did that still no dice!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import images into Magento, use ImportExport (what you call "import") with the following sample CSV:

```
sku,_media_image,_media_attribute_id,_media_is_disabled,_media_position,_media_lable,image,small_image,thumbnail
1234567,img1.jpg,77,1,1,Image 1,img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img2.jpg
,img2.jpg,77,0,2,Image 2,,,     
,img3.jpg,77,0,3,Image 3,,,
```

The files must be in /media/import/. In your sample, most of the *media** fields are missing.

You can get the value for the `_media_attribute_id` by calling

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getAttributeId();
```

Comment: I am followed all your steps, but not working,  my excel format http://i.imgur.com/T0T6Wvj.png

Comment: and my error http://i.imgur.com/yUWdbLu.png

Comment: @JeevaRathinam The fields above are for existing products. For new products, you need a few more fields. See https://www.integer-net.com/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/ for a detailed description.